# expected value of least squares parameters

Tags: mathematical-statistics, covariance

I'm having some trouble with this equation from the least squares model.

$$E[\parallel  \mathcal {\hat {B}}  \parallel ^2] = [E\parallel  \mathcal {\hat {B}}  \parallel] ^2 + trace ( \text {cov} [\mathcal {\hat {B}}])$$

$$ =\parallel  \mathcal {\hat {B}}  \parallel ^2   +  \sigma_{e}^2 trace((X^{T}X)^{-1})$$

We have $\mathcal {\hat {B}}= (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y$, so we should have

$$\text {cov} [\mathcal {\hat {B}}]=\text {cov}[(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}(Y)]$$

$$=(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\text {cov}[Y]  (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}$$
$$=(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\sigma_{e}^2I(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}$$

$$= \sigma_{e}^2(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}$$

I'm stuck at this point. A little clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: $\text{cov}(AX) = A\, \text{cov}(X)\, A^T$. You have written $\text{cov}(AX) = A\, \text{cov}(X)\, A$, which isn't even conformable. If you fix that you get a nice cancellation. This looks like routine bookwork and should carry the `self-study` tag (which helps notify prospective answers to give hints and guidance rather than just do the whole problem for you).

Answer (score 1):

The non-random parts should form an outer product when you break them out of the covariance.

$$\begin{align*}
cov(\hat\beta) &= cov[(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY] \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T cov(Y) ((X^TX)^{-1}X^T)^T \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T cov(Y) X^{TT} (X^TX)^{-1T} \\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T cov(Y) X (X^TX)^{-1} \quad\text{ (the pseudo-inverse is symmetric)}\\
&= (X^TX)^{-1}X^T \sigma_e^2 I X (X^TX)^{-1} \\
&= \sigma_e^2 (X^TX)^{-1}X^T  X (X^TX)^{-1} \\
&= \sigma_e^2 (X^TX)^{-1}
\end{align*}$$

so

$trace(cov(\hat\beta)) = \sigma_e^2 trace((X^TX)^{-1})$, which is how you get the second equality. The first equality comes from the law of total variance, but it looks like you already understood that part.